# How to open an url on webview on click firebase notification?

Tags: php, android, firebase

I'm using php for to send notification. When I add click_action as a parameter, there is nothing on click notification. App doesn't open. But if I don't send click_action everything is okay, app is opening. But of course main page. I just want to specific url on webview on click to notification. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
$msg = array
                  (
                'body'  => 'Test Test',
                'title' => 'Test',
                'click_action' => 'https://google.com/',
                'icon'  => 'smallicon',/*Default Icon*/
                 'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
                  );
            $fields = array
                    (
                        'to'        => 'token',
                        'notification'  => $msg
                    );


            $headers = array
                    (
                        'Authorization: key=',
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                $result = curl_exec($ch );
                curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: please share android app code that handles firebase notification and app opening